# AWS S3 - How to allow GET method but disable POST and PUT, unless using pre-signed URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

The bucket I've created is used to store data about my customers (Static files).
To save data (put an object into the storage), I'm using the pre-signed URL feature, so the client-side is responsible to make the requests to the S3 bucket, and it should only be allowed using pre-signed URL, obviously.
Beyond data savings, I would like that customers will have the ability to access the data within the bucket (read access) without the need of using pre-signed URL, but configure allowed origins as well.

So to sum up, I need the bucket to allow read access without pre-signed URL, but block write access, unless there's a pre-signed url involved.
Is it even possible to achieve?

I'm using serverless framework to configure the bucket, here's the code:

```
    MyBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        BucketName: my-bucket
        AccessControl: Private
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
          BlockPublicAcls: true
          BlockPublicPolicy: true
          IgnorePublicAcls: true
          RestrictPublicBuckets: true
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedHeaders:
                - '*'
              AllowedMethods:
                - HEAD
                - GET
                - PUT
                - POST
              AllowedOrigins: <list of allowed origins>
```

**Is it possible to configure it with multiple policies only? Without using CloudFront solution?**

Answer (score 2):

You can serve the content using CloudFront from your S3 in order to give read-access but keep the bucket private. You would give CloudFront access to GetObject from the S3 bucket. See here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#oac-permission-to-access-s3

You would delegate write access to IAM, via your pre-signed URL functionality. If the signer has write access to the bucket then whomever uses that URL will also have write access. So the URL acts as the permission for the user. You don't need an explicit deny as its not explicitly allowed unless you have the pre-signed URL. You could look into this to see if any of these example bucket policies would help:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/bucket-policy-s3-sigv4-conditions.html#bucket-policy-sig-v4-condition-key-example

In short, the bucket policy will *only* allow reads from CloudFront and the pre-signed URL is the *only* way to allow writes to S3 in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. Do toy know If I can configure multiple bucket policies for read and write, without the need of using CloudFront?

Comment: @Askish Yes, you can add multiple statements in your policy. IMO, I would make an API in your backend to fetch the objects you want. This way your bucket can stay private and you have easy control. Doing this would allow you to only allow you to only allow GetObject calls from that API.

Comment: Can you write me the full policy that will match my requierments (I don't want to use CloudFront or API for fetching, however I do want to keep the bucket disabled for write operations unless using pre-signed urls). Once it works I'll check your answer as correct one.